# MapBox on Android: Receive Location Updates while App is in Background

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm trying to implement a simple location tracker using the MapBox Android SDK. I want continuous tracking even if the app runs in the background. In the MapBox sample at as well as in the API documentation it is state that MapView.onPause() must be called in activity's onPause. But if this is called, tracking stops and I don't receive location updates.

Here's my onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            mapbox = mapboxMap;
            mapbox.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mapbox.getMyLocation();
            mapbox.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
}
```

And here's the onLocationChangedListener

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(@Nullable Location location) {
    if(location != null) {
        if(locationList.size() == 0 || !areEqual(location, locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1))){
            locationList.add(location);
            location.getSpeed();
            computeDistance();
            addPolyline();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a recommended way to receive MapBox location updates if the app is in the background? Is there a custom service implementation or something like that? If not, would it be sufficient to just call MapView.onDestory()?
Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: any solution found?